# why does it call bool_function first?

Tags: c++

I am curious about the following code, somebody could explain why does it call bool func first ? isn`t "str" more suitable for arg type string ?

```
 void a(bool input)
    {
        cout<<"I amd first"<<endl;
        cout<<input<<endl;
    }

    void a(const string &input)
    {
        cout<<"I amd second"<<endl;
        cout<<input<<endl;
    }

    int main( )
    {
        a("str");  //  call  void a(bool input)

        a(string("str"));   //call  void a(const string &input)

        return 0; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"str"` is of type `const char[4]`, which decays immediately to `const char *`, and the conversion from any pointer type to `bool` is considered *before* non-explicit constructors to custom types.

So, I'd say that the answer is "because the standard says so".

The relevant passage should be 13.3.3.2 ¶2:

> When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as defined in 13.3.3.1)
>
> - a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence [...]

Comment: ... where conversion from `const char*` to `std::string` is a "user-defined conversion sequence" because it involves a class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it is because when you call a("str"), you're trying to call a function with parameters const char *. It will convert any type of pointer to bool before any other implicit conversion (::std::string etc).

Comment: any other *user defined* conversion.